# Grandparent state is not updating from onFocus in Grandchild in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React component like below:

```
<GrandParent />
<Parent />
<Child />
```

Now I have few input fields in child component. I want to update grandparent state when user focus child component input control.

Grandparent code:

```js
const GrandParent=()=>
{
  const [focusDiv, setFocusDiv] = useState(false);
  return (
  <>
  <h1>GrandParent</h1>
  <p>{focusDiv}</p>
  <Parent setFocusDiv={setFocusDiv} />
  </>
  )
}
```

Parent code:

```js
const Parent=()=>
{
  return (
  <>
  <h1>Parent</h1>
  <Child setFocusDiv={props.setFocusDiv} />
  </>
  )
}
```

Child code:

```js
const Child=()=>
{

  function focus_fun(e) {
    if(e.target.id == "textID"){
        props.setFocusDiv(true);
      }
  }


  return (
  <>
  <h1>Child</h1>
  <input type="text" id="textID" onFocus={focus_fun} />
  </>
  )
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: Is the condition `e.target.id == "textID"` really needed ? I mean, since onFocus is on the input, it will always be true. Except if you use `focus_fun` elsewhere also

Comment: I'm using id because i have multiple input and i want to update state as per focused input.

Comment: You are not passing the props... `props.setFocusDiv()` is `undefined` because you are not passing the function down to the child component.

Comment: its working on parentslevel but not working on grandparent level.

Answer (score 1):

You should also receive `props` in your `Child` and `Parent`

```
const Child=(props)=>
{

  function focus_fun(e) {
    if(e.target.id == "textID"){
        props.setFocusDiv(true);
      }
  }


  return (
  <>
  <h1>Child</h1>
  <input type="text" id="textID" onFocus={focus_fun} />
  </>
  )
}
```

Same for `Parent`

Answer (score 1):

#### Mehod #1

(not extensible very much and need to pass props around)

You need to define `props` input for your components pass the props from grandparent to child and also convert the boolean to a string otherwise it won't render the value:

```js
const GrandParent = () => {
  const [focusDiv, setFocusDiv] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>GrandParent</h1>
      <p>{focusDiv.toString()}</p>
      <Parent setFocusDiv={setFocusDiv} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const Parent = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Parent</h1>
      <Child setFocusDiv={props.setFocusDiv} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const Child = (props) => {
  function focus_fun(e) {
    if (e.target.id == "textID") {
      props.setFocusDiv(true);
    }
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Child</h1>
      <input type="text" id="textID" onFocus={focus_fun} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<GrandParent />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

#### Mehod #2

Use [CreateContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) and [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hooks to pass the state and setter methods directly to any child in the tree without using props:

```js
const FocusContext = React.createContext();

const GrandParent = () => {
  const [focusDiv, setFocusDiv] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>GrandParent</h1>
      <p>{focusDiv.toString()}</p>
      <FocusContext.Provider value={{ focusDiv, setFocusDiv }}>
        <Parent />
      </FocusContext.Provider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Parent</h1>
      <Child />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const Child = () => {
  const focus = React.useContext(FocusContext);

  function focus_fun(e) {
    if (e.target.id == "textID") {
      focus.setFocusDiv(true);
    }
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Child</h1>
      <input type="text" id="textID" onFocus={focus_fun} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<GrandParent />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```